# Visual Basic generate random number

Tags: vb.net, random

I am new to coding and I want to make a simple program that moves a windows to a random location on your desktop.
Right now my code is this:

```
    Me.Location = New Point(27, 55)
    Me.Location = New Point(502, 624)
    Me.Location = New Point(858, 477)
    Me.Location = New Point(564, 50)
    Me.Location = New Point(898, 41)
    Me.Location = New Point(468, 944)
    Me.Location = New Point(417, 7)
    Me.Location = New Point(841, 697)
    Me.Location = New Point(953, 438)
```

I had to put in the code myself so it will never be completely random and will always repeat itself.
How do I make the numbers a random number?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx if you use Stack Overflow as your search engine you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: `Dim random As New Random` then you can use it as `random.Next()`. A little of [this](https://www.google.com) would have helped you. Eminem wouldn't be proud of you Stan!

Comment: Is google down? No!

Comment: Simple stuff really: http://i.imgur.com/vea0apD.png
But you should consider using Google or even search here on SO for the answer before you ask, since basic stuff like this has probably been answered before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare this variable in the scope of the class:

```
Dim rnd As New Random
```

Then put this code in whatever event you want to use to set the window to a random position:

```
Me.Location = New Point(rnd.Next(0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width), rnd.Next(0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height))
```

This will also make sure that the window will always stay within the bounds of the screen when put to a new random position.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to use the [Rnd()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=vs.90).aspx) function

> Rnd() generates a number n, 0<= n < 1
>   so if you want to generate a number between 1 and 10, you need to add +1, as multiplying Rnd() with 10 will give you numbers between 0 and 9.